# how to approved wordpress theme on wordpress org theme directory?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like to contribute to the WordPress community by submitting a free theme in the WordPress theme directory. can anybody please suggest and help me to approve in the WordPress org directory.

Comment: This doesn't assist to be programming-related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily submit your theme to wordpress the only thing which you should be careful about is that it follows basic guidelines. 
Checkout original wordpress link it will help you more..

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/release/submitting-your-theme-to-wordpress-org/